# Can not see Button at bottom

Tags: android

in Xml file i can not see button at bottom my code is here please help me

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background">
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/navigationbar" android:layout_below="@+id/top"
    android:id="@+id/toptext" android:layout_height="50dip">
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/back"
        android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip" android:layout_margin="10dip" android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></Button>
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="@string/source_of_stress"
        android:textSize="20dip" android:layout_marginLeft="100dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/date" android:layout_below="@+id/toptext"
    android:gravity="center" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button android:id="@+id/previous" android:background="@drawable/left_arrow"
        android:visibility="gone" android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="20dip" android:layout_height="23dip"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF" />
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/datebar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip" android:paddingRight="10dip">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/currentDate" android:textSize="19sp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#2972cc" android:text="Monday" android:textStyle="bold" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/next" android:background="@drawable/right_arrow"
            android:visibility="gone" android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_width="20dip" android:layout_height="23dip"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
<!--
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" android:textSize="11sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dip" android:layout_below="@+id/date"
    android:id="@+id/all_sos_text" android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView> <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/list_scroll" android:layout_marginBottom="55dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/date"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip" android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:scrollbars="none">
-->
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/sos_scroll"
    android:layout_marginBottom="82dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/date"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip" android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:scrollbars="none">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/sos_lin" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ListView android:paddingLeft="1dip" android:scrollbars="none"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" android:focusable="true"
            android:id="@+id/list" android:dividerHeight="2dip"
            android:footerDividersEnabled="false" android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dip" android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
            android:background="@drawable/newshape_list"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dip" android:paddingRight="1dip"
            android:layout_height="230dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:fadingEdge="none" android:divider="#A9ABAD"></ListView>
        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" android:layout_marginBottom="50dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/list">
            <TableLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/add_table" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@drawable/listback" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:stretchColumns="1">
                <TableRow android:id="@+id/add_data">
                    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/addbuttonimage" android:id="@+id/que1"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
                    <TextView android:text="Add New Stress..."
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                        android:textSize="15sp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="3dip" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sos_scroll" android:id="@+id/donerel"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    <Button android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:text="Save"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@drawable/savebutton" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/done"></Button>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Where is the rest of XML? your tags are broken

Comment: ok i posted here full xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that the layout is not showing is `layout_marginBottom="82dip"` on the `ScrollView`

So changing:

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/sos_scroll"
    android:layout_marginBottom="82dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/date"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip" android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:scrollbars="none">
```

to for example:

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/sos_scroll"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/date"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip" android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:scrollbars="none">
```

should help.